# Differential expression between two types of cells of specific marker gene expression

Tags: seurat

I want to define the identity of some cells based on a gene marker (for example the colour yellow< EYFP gene). One group of cells has the EYFP gene the other doesn't and I want to find the differential gene expression between those groups that are found on the same cell sample. Do you have any tips for a code in Seurat? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the section **"Finding Differentialy Expressed Feautres (cluster biomarkers)"** of [Seurat tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.0/pbmc3k_tutorial.html).

You have to define your clusters (if not computed automatically) by modifying the ***ident*** slot of the Seurat object.

Then you call the function *FindMarkers* of your Seurat object (to define markers of a given cluster against the rest) or *FindAllMarkers* (to look for all the combinations)

Comment: How can I modify the ident slot based on a gene and not on a cell population ?

Comment: You should decide which cells express your EYPF marker and then give this information to the ident slot.

Comment: The cells are dispersed all over the tSNE plot and are not within a specific cell cluster. How do I group them together>

Comment: You can create your own clusters/grouping by expression. For instance, all the cells that express more than 10 molecules of EYPF you assign them to a group and the rest to other. This has nothing to do with the tSNE plot at the end, is a matter of grouping cells by expression of a marker gene. Then you assign the manual clusters that you have created via the ident slot and perform differential expression.

Comment: I am new to this and don't know the exact syntax. Could you provide a specific code for defining the ident slot, please? That would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: I mean I don't know how to group cells based on gene expression

Comment: @plat Hi plat, can you give me the detailed code about assign the manual cluster that I can create via the ident slot and perform differential expression?