# Set new Idents based on gene expression in Seurat and mix n match identities to compare using FindAllMarkers

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, covid-19, sars-cov-2

I am relatively new to Bioinformatics and scRNA-seq data analysis. I am using Seurat V3 to analyze a scRNA-seq dataset in R. Currently, I have merged three scRNA-seq samples from the same donor into one Seurat object, *All_Samples*. We'll call them:

1. Uninfected
2. Virus1
3. Virus2

   ```
   All_Samples <- merge(x = Uninfected, y = c(Virus1, Virus2))
   ```

Uninfected cells did not receive virus (i.e. express no viral genes), the other two samples were infected with a virus introducing new genes into the cells. I would like to accomplish two things.

**First**: I want to create a new Ident for Virus1 and Virus2 samples based on expression of a viral gene  of interest: "GeneA". All cells from Virus1 and Virus2 samples that have "GeneA" expression > 0.5 would be labeled "Pos", those with "GeneA" < 0.5 would be labeled "Neg" in a  the new Column called GeneA.

I am able to subset the objects based on GeneA expression that applies to all samples in the object. For example:

```
All_Samples_GeneA_Pos <- subset(All_Samples, subset = GeneA > 0.5)
All_Samples_GeneA_Neg <- subset(All_Samples, subset = GeneA < 0.5)
```

I assume I would have to modify All_Samples@meta.data based on [this](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/manually-define-clusters-in-seurat-and-determine-marker-genes) post and [this](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/8658/how-to-set-new-identities-for-new-clusters-based-on-a-gene-expression-in-seurat) post, but I admit I'm not entirely sure how to implement the suggested answers into my data.

**Second**: Once I have separated the data from Virus1 and Virus2 into "Pos" and "Neg" cells for "GeneA", I want to look for differentially expressed genes between all Uninfected cells and "Pos" cells from Virus1 or Virus2. I have been using something like this to compare samples:

```
 FindMarkers(object = All_Samples, group.by = 'virus', ident.1 = "1", ident.2 = "2")
```

But how would I do something equivalent to this:

```
 FindMarkers(object = All_Samples, ident.1 = "Uninfected", ident.2 = "Virus1_GeneA_Pos")
```

Or maybe

```
 FindMarkers(object = All_Samples, ident.1 = "Uninfected_GeneA_Neg", ident.2 = "Virus1_GeneA_Pos")
```

Let me know if I can clarify any points. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can use `ifelse()` to create a new column in the `meta.data` slot:

```
All_Samples@meta.data$new_column <-
  ifelse(
    rownames(All_Samples@meta.data) %in% colnames(All_Samples_GeneA_Pos),
    "GeneA_Pos",
    "GeneB_Pos"
  )
```

`colnames(seurat_object)` provides a vector of cell names in a given `Seurat` object. Here whatever cell that is in the `All_Samples_GeneA_Pos` object would be `GeneA_Pos` and whatever is not `GeneB_Pos`. To better control the behavior, you can use a "nested" `ifelse()`; you can have another `ifelse()` instead of the `"GeneB_Pos"` bit above.

For the second question, the rationale is the same as above, you can define an extra column with the "identities of interest", then use these identities with `SetIdent()` and then in turn using two identities of interest in the differential expression call.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was very helpful.